# Batch Files - How to output information from them in more than one instance

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is it possible to output information from a batch file, with multiple outputs.

E.g.

```
test.bat > output.txt
```

then 20 seconds later create a new file

```
test.bat > output2.txt
```

etc. (With the process still running)

Comment: Very hard to achieve. One way would be to create files that you use as an indicator how many instances are running. But generally I would say you should try to accept the limits of NT scripts and move on to an alternative. And that's from someone having written a widely used NT script in excess of 40 KiB.

Comment: The simplest answer is probably no, but if you can give us some more context on what you are trying to do, perhaps we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need to give up just cause you're limited to batch. This can be achieved quite easy

```
@ECHO off
:: Check if the script has ran before, and set the iteration
IF EXIST next.txt (
FOR /F "tokens=1" %I in (next.txt) DO SET /A _result=%I+1> next.txt
) else (
SET /A _result=^1> next.txt
)
:: Now the iteration is stored in a variable named %_result%

echo test > output%_result%.txt
```

If you download a copy of sed for windows it shouldn't be too hard to achieve a unique name with chronology.

```
time /t | sed "s/:/_/g" | sed "s/ /_/">>time.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%I IN (time.txt) DO echo test >> output-%%I.txt
```

Note: if you're using Win Vista/7 you'll need to change this to %I instead of %%I

Comment: The `%I` syntax is for using directly at the command prompt, the `%%I` one for using in batch scripts. Works the same in all NTs, including Vista/7.